# How does neural networks metrics functions work?

Tags: keras, metrics, floating-accuracy, recurrent-neural-network

Here is keras metrics functions definition:

```
def binary_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
  return K.mean(K.equal(y_true, K.round(y_pred)), axis=-1)


def categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
  return K.cast(
      K.equal(K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1), K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)), K.floatx())
```

For example, if I have NN with output layer of 2 neurons, which can be:
[0, 1] or
[1, 0] and use metrics=binary_accuracy

when I run my NN for training, it always shows some accuracy value for every batch. How it counts this? Is it like, when prediced value is greater than 0.5 - it is 1, when that value less than 0.5 - it is 0?

Answer (score 0):

As you figured out, there are many possible ways to define *an* accuracy, and in general it's hard to say what the best solution is. This will also depend on how you're going to later use that network.

But to take the case of `binary_accuracy`, it indeed compares the *rounded* predictions with the binary training data. Now that doesn't mean the accuracy is 1 when the output is >0.5. It means the accuracy is 1 when the *difference* between output and training target is <0.5.

In words: the network is accurate when the output is close to what it should be.

Comment: Are you sure that it compares difference with 0.5?

Comment: @DmitryNalyvaiko: Well, I don't think `K.round` is going to round 0.4 up to 1.0, so yes that's what it mathematically means.

Comment: but how it calculates difference of vectors? it is like "vector1 - vector2" or "length(vector1) - length(vector2)"?

Comment: moreover K.round uses only single y_pred. how it can compare differece with 0.5 if it has only 1 operand?

Comment: @DmitryNalyvaiko: you appear to be struggling with basic math expressions.

Comment: I only asked question